# One ui-block in the center of a grid - jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I used grid in jquery mobile to design the page. I want a block to be placed exactly in the middle.

First inside a grid there will be 2 block, equally placed, in the next grid there will be one block, I want that to be centered.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NrCGb/600/)

I tried few tricks like

```
margin: 0 auto
```

None of them worked yet. How can I take a `ui-block` in the middle and have the same width as the upper 2 block?
(codes are inside jsfiddle)

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/NrCGb/626/

Comment: @Aravin first 2 block width and last block width aren't same in that jsfiddle. It has to be same width for all. Yet if no efficient answer pops up,then I might need to use that trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the JQM `ui-block-a` class and here your block width will be same as a block in first grid. Try this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/NrCGb/637/)

**CHANGES :** Added **margin-left:25%;** in your second grid .

**Code:**

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div id="content" data-role="content">
        <div class="ui-grid-a" id="mymenu">
                    <div class="ui-block-a image_class" id="daily_sehri_iftar" style="background:#000000;"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="text-align: center">hhh</div></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b image_class" id="monthly_sehri_iftar" style="background:#000000;"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="text-align: center">aaaa</div></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-a" id="mymenu">
                    <div class="ui-block-a image_class" id="prayer_time" style="background:#000000;margin-left:25%;"><div class="ui-bar ui-bar-a" style="text-align: center;">aaaaa</div></div>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```